# Jquery resizable seems to change layout

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, resize, jquery-ui-resizable

Please refer to the J Fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/NwvPA/3/

The two bars, you can resize them left and right only.  However, if you resize the top one, it repositions the other bar ontop of it, they should stay at their vertical level!

It's hard to post code in here because there's quite a lot, all the relevant bits are stripped out and put on the fiddle.

Any help appreciated, thank you!

Comment: Hmm seems the problem comes from a conjunction of resizable + draggable : remove the draggable, and it works.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/NwvPA/8/  subtenante seems to have the right idea

Comment: @John @Sub thanks, gives me something to go on at least!  I remember having problems getting both to work together before :-(

Comment: Fixed :D  Used parent, $(".jobArea .bar").parent().draggable... fixes it.  I think resizable adds a wrapper div or something?

Comment: lol i was just about to say, jquery seems to get all the children when you select a parent, its odd but yea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed it in the end:

```
// Bar dragability
$(".jobArea .bar").parent().draggable(
    {
        axis: "x",
        grid: [GridSize, GridSize]
    }
);
```

I beleive the resizable adds a wrapper div, so if we select the parent it works bug free.